# How to increase the default time out for SSH on OS X?

Tags: macos, ssh

How to increase the default time out when trying to connect to a remote machine via SSH on Mac OS X?

```
ssh -D 9999 user@host
```

Answer (score 21):

You need to change the `ServerAliveInterval`, as explained in [`ssh_config(5)`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ssh_config%205):

> Sets a timeout interval in seconds after which if no data has
>   been received from the server, ssh will send a message through
>   the encrypted channel to request a response from the server.  The
>   default is 0, indicating that these messages will not be sent to
>   the server.

For example, create `~/.ssh/config` and add:

```
Host *
    ServerAliveInterval 120
```

This will apply to all connections. For a single connection, just use the `-o` option as explained in [`ssh(1)`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ssh%201):

```
ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=120 user@host
```

Comment: Why I'm still getting     ssh: connect to host hostname port 22: Operation timed out

Comment: Well, then this is not the answer to your actual problem. Why didn't you include the error message in your question? This is a completely different issue and most likely a problem with the server itself. You can either rewrite your question to state the *actual* problem that you have (in that case I'll delete my answer) … or accept this and ask a new question. Whatever makes more sense to you.

Comment: Just leave this answer up. Not your problem that the user didn't bother to ask the right question.

Answer (score 6):

Specify the option "ConnectTimeout" for connection timeout, eg

```
ssh -o ConnectTimeout=240 -D 9999 user@host
```

Or in *~/.ssh/config* add

```
Host *
  ConnectTimeout 240
```

Comment: Thanks. But somehow does not work for me longer than 60s (it works with 10), maybe there's a hard limit set somewhere else?